# Garage band app-file recovery?

Tags: recovery, file, garageband

I dropped my iphone4s in water and when I got a new phone and brought back the GarageBand app none of my songs were there. Is there ANYWAY I can recover these files?

Answer (score 1):

iOS stores backups in two places:

- iCloud - sign in to your account and see if a backup of the device is stored there. With the files app on iOS 11 and browsable iCloud storage on macOS this might be the easiest bet.
- iTunes device backup or sync - check iTunes on each computer you may have connected it to recently, when you sync to a computer, it will make backups of your songs and other data
- iCloud device backup - restoring an iCloud entire backup of the phone data might also get you the files back or so you can export them elsewhere.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946